# What is keeping jQuery.print from working with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, leaflet

When testing a git repo that makes use of jQuery.print ([demo here](http://rowanwins.github.com/leaflet-easyPrint/)), I got the following error:

```
[Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

I tested this on a local Leaflet instance with jQuery.print by pasting the following into the console, and was able to replicate it:

```
$.print("map" /*, options*/);

[Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
"Failed to print from iframe" undefined "The operation is insecure." jQuery.print.js:141
$.fn.print() jQuery.print.js:141
<anonymous function> debugger eval code:1
```

This also happened even if I disabled the option to build an iframe for printing:

```
$("map").print({
    addGlobalStyles : true,
    stylesheet : null,
    rejectWindow : true,
    noPrintSelector : ".no-print",
    iframe : false,
    append : null,
    prepend : null
});

[Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: "<unknown>"]
```

The [jQuery.print demo](http://doersguild.github.io/jQuery.print/demo/) itself works fine on my machine. Why does mixing it with Leaflet create security errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is [the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - unless images are requested with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), they trigger this security issue in browsers. [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) re-requests images to work around this.