# Leaflet OpenStreetMap Image Export with Map Markers using html2canvas

Tags: java, javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, html2canvas

I am trying to export `leaftlet` map with `markers` to `PNG` format using `html2canvas`.

Issue is html2canvas is able to create PNG of Map but not with the Markers on the map. No sure about the reason but I guess because of the layering, it is creating PNG of map layer only.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lup55pa6/1/

Would be great if someone can provide me solution with existing APIs I am using OR I can consider other export options as well if possible in any JS library or Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is keeping jQuery.print from working with Leaflet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172591/what-is-keeping-jquery-print-from-working-with-leaflet)

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem to export the leaflet map with the markers,

At the end I created the map in the server (Node)

I wrote a post, How to export the leaflet map to pdf, see link below

[Export leaflet map to pdf report](https://orenw.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/export-leaflet-map-to-image/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that leaflet is adding the markers as svg which html2canvas cannot render (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95)

You should be able to force leaflet into using canvas instead of svg though by setting the `L_PREFER_CANVAS` flag to true as seen here: https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/blob/master/debug/vector/vector-canvas.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Openlayers 3 for doing this. Because you have a security issue with , you can't use html2canvas at least I tried (in the documentation says that you can't render iframes). Here is my code, hope will help.

HTML
  < a id="export-png" class="download-pdf" download="map.png" title="Descargar">< /a>

Javascript

function drawMap() {
    var map = new ol.Map({
           layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
           target: 'map',
           controls: ol.control.defaults({
                 attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                   })
          }),
          view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([geografic.longitud,geografic.latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'),
                zoom: 8
           })
  });

var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');
  exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
              var canvas = event.context.canvas;
              window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
       });
       map.renderSync();
      }, false);
}